# Is it insecure to set password & password_confirmation for has_secure_password to an oauth token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, omniauth

So currently instead of writing a bunch of code to work around the use of has_secure_password with OmniAuth I'm just setting the password and password_confirmation to the OAuth token that gets returned by twitter/facebook/whatever during user creation. My question is, is this insanely insecure? It kind of feels like it is but I'm not really sure what the risks are. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is insecure. do not do that people can steal your access token and/or hack your accounts.